# Facebook post to Wall Javascript HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

I would like to see best way of posting to Facebook from a HTML 5 game I will need to pull data from my javascript file to post to facebook I tryed adding.

```
FB.init({
    appId: "309749382423000",
    status: true,
    cookie: true
});

function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://google.com/',
        picture: 'http://google.com',
        name: ' Run!',
        caption: 'I just got a highscore of' + points2,
        description: 'Try to beat my score!.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

This was added to my index file and it will not pull the var points2 that changes each time you play the game so would like some help with trying to add Post to facebook in html5 canvus

**EDIT:** wanted to post the full code The post to facebook works but the game is HTML5 so the javscript file keeps running in the game and the code above is in my index file that does not loop so it loads but will not run pull the "points2" var  in to the facebook code. So real question would be how to add facebook post to canvus HTML5 game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the user is already authenticated with your app use:

```js
FB.getLoginStatus( function ( response ) {
    if ( response.authResponse ) {
        FB.api( 
            '/me/feed',
            'post',
            {
                message: '',
                name: 'Run!',
                caption: 'I just got a highscore of ' + points2,
                description: 'Try to beat my score!.',
                link: 'https://google.com/',
                picture: 'https://google.com/pic.png'
            },
            function ( response ) {
                if ( response.id ) {
                    //success
                } else {
                    //failure
                };
            }
        );
    };
} );
```

​

Comment: @user1302560 I posted this before you updated your code. You would call the code based on some event in your application (button click, game ending, etc).

Comment: wraap it in a function like function postStatus() {//the above code} then call it somehow, maybe a button trigger, touch event, timeout...that is your choise